# How to add PHP Fiddle link in my answer

Tags: support, hyperlinks

I am a PHP developer. Sometimes I answer questions tagged [`php`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php). So I test the code on PHP Fiddle and then put my answer. But if I want to refer the reader to my PHP Fiddle sample, then how do I do that? Is there a tool in Stack Overflow to include the PHP Fiddle named link? The link I can create using Fiddle looks like:

```
//phpfiddle.org/lite?code=<?php\necho "hello";\n\n?>\n
```

But it looks so weird and includes the code in the link. So if the code is too long then Fiddle does not allow me to create a link. Is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If PHP Fiddle only allows you to create a code link by including all the code on the URL you're limited to what both Stack Exchange and the browsers of the users allow. You can of course use the link markup to produce something like this:

> [php fiddle with > 4000 characters of code](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnecho%20%22hello%22;%5Cn%5Cn?%3E)

It looks like Stack Exchange allows this and my Chrome browser nor PHP Fiddle choked on it.

You can achieve this by doing this in your markup:

```
[name the link][phpcode]

  [phpcode]: http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C? ... 4000 characters
```

You can put the phpcode at the end of your post so it doesn't clutter up your post. Feel free to look at the [source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/47e3b08e-1b4f-44d5-83a2-571e3b61b182/view-source) of this answer to see the exact markdown.

Comment: you can only output simple words like echo, useless

Comment: @csandreas1 it is not my nor SE's fault that phpfiddle.org is a useless service on its own.

Comment: or maybe there is a way to share but we don't know how ?

Comment: @csandreas1 sure, if that option now exists, feel free to post that as an answer

Comment: see my code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p14k-89dt

Comment: The OP is using lite, so they didn't sign-up.

Comment: You have to register at PhpFiddle to produce PhpFiddle lite link

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to share a PhpFiddle project

1. Sign up on http://phpfiddle.org/
2. Add your code and click "Save as"
3. Choose the first radio button (Save the code in public status)
4. Click submit and copy the link

Examples:

> Open the code with PhpFiddle -
>   http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g35q-nkdp
>  Open the code with
>   PhpFiddle Lite - http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/g35q-nkdp